# check whether animation from modalViewController is finished

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I had tried presenting a `UIPopoverController` on a `viewWillAppear` on a view presented via a `modal view controller`. However when doing so the `UIPopoverController` immediately got dismissed. Any idea why this might have happened and the right way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do any view handling in `-viewWillAppear`, because there is no guarantee that the view has loaded.  Move all implementations into `-viewDidAppear` for safer execution.